# Remove blank choice in a drop down field

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to get rid of the very first blank choice that populates all the drop down fields on my form.

[image: blank choice - drop down]

How do I do that?

Comment: Hello! We currently do not support the ability to delete the blank choice option. In the case that a field is not required, that option allows users to leave the field blank. If you don't want the field to appear blank on your form, I would recommend setting the first choice option as the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not have a way to remove this blank section in the drop down list, unless you want to enable 'Allow Fill In' for the Choice field.

Comment: Is there at least a way to add text to this blank field (i.e. "pick a choice")?